# Missing right parenthesis SQL - *

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble with this piece of code, as it is saying "Error at line 22
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" when I execute it.

```
SELECT DC.ACJ_ID,
           DC.MCI_UNIQ_ID,
           DG.GENDER_COMMON_DESC,
           DR.RACE_COMMON_DESC,
           AD.ADDRESS_LINE_1,
           AD.ADDRESS_LINE_2,
           AD.CITY,
           AD.STATE,
           AD.ZIP_CD,
           AD.ZIP_CD_9,
           DC_RANK
      FROM DW_CLNTVIEW.FACT_CLIENT_WEEK_LATEST FCAS,
           DW.DIM_GENDER DG,
           DW.DIM_RACE DR,
           DW.DIM_ADDRESS AD,
           KLISA.JAIL_IDS DOC,
           (SELECT ACJ_ID,
                   MCI_UNIQ_ID,
                   DENSE_RANK ()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY ACJ_ID
                         ORDER BY END_DATE DESC, EFF_DATE DESC, MCI_UNIQ_ID DESC ---REMOVE “MCI_UNIQ_ID DESC” TO ALLOW DUPLICATES ON ACJ_ID
                      DC_RANK
              FROM DW.DIM_CLIENT) DC
    WHERE     FCAS.RACE_KEY = DR.RACE_KEY(+)
           AND FCAS.SRC_SYS_KEY(+) = 0
           AND FCAS.GENDER_KEY = DG.GENDER_KEY(+)
           AND FCAS.ADDRESS_KEY = AD.ADDRESS_KEY(+)
           AND DC.MCI_UNIQ_ID = FCAS.MCI_UNIQ_ID(+)
           AND ACJS.ACJ_ID = DC.ACJ_ID(+)
           AND DC_RANK(+) = 1;
```

Comment: Just tried- same issue.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis in your rank code.

Comment: Use this...`DENSE_RANK ()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY ACJ_ID
                         ORDER BY END_DATE DESC, EFF_DATE DESC, MCI_UNIQ_ID DESC) ---REMOVE “MCI_UNIQ_ID DESC” TO ALLOW DUPLICATES ON ACJ_ID`
                      DC_RANK

Comment: Listen to your errors; they don't just get flung at random.  If you look through your query, you will see that your Parenthesis don't match up.  If you ever have this error, try counting your open braces and comparing it to a count of your close braces.

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause and learn how to express an `OUTER JOIN` using ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You have unbalanced parenthesis.

```
(SELECT ACJ_ID,
```

Left.

```
 OVER (PARTITION BY ACJ_ID
```

Another left.

```
FROM DW.DIM_CLIENT) DC
```

Closed one pair.

Thus leaving one open.